# Prepared statements with TBS

Tags: tinybutstrong

I'm trying to merge the results of a prepared statement to TBS. Here's my code:

```
$s = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM newsletters WHERE newsletter_id = :newsletter_id");
$s->bindParam(":newsletter_id",$newsletter_id);
$s->execute();
$newsletter = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$tbs->MergeBlock('$newsletter ',  $newsletter );
```

But I can't get the results fields. I get errors like the following:

> TinyButStrong Error in field [newsletter.title...]: item 'title' is not an existing key in the array.

I can't find my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MergeBlock()` is for merging a recordset , so you should use `$s->fetchAll()` instead of `$s->fetch()`. The section of the template will be repeated for each record.

But if you have to merge a standalone record, use `MergeField()` instead of `MergeBlock()`. The single fields will be merged one by one without repeating.